# Gremlin Traversal Bulking (OLTP)

Tags: gremlin

While i understand the principle of Bulking, i am curious to know how does the machine make that happen from a programatic point of you. How to detect that multiple Traverser are on the same node, to decide to merge and bulk them. Is there any description somewhere of the algorithm used for detecting that a specific situation requires a Bulk.

Also, what are the explicits Step that would trigger a bulk. Is there any instructions that can be added to the traversal that will make the bulk happen explicitly ?

Answer (score 2):

Bulking typically occurs in relation to a `barrier()` step and is discussed a bit in TinkerPop's reference documentation [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#barrier-step). Most folks don't use `barrier()` directly in their Gremlin writing (though you can) as various Traversal Strategies built into TinkerPop (like `LazyBarrierStrategy` as an example) try to automatically inject them into the traversal in places where they might do some good.

You can see where/when `barrier()` steps are being injected by doing an `explain()` on your traversal:

```
gremlin> g.V().out().both().explain()
==>Traversal Explanation
=======================================================================================================================================
Original Traversal                 [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]

ConnectiveStrategy           [D]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
IncidentToAdjacentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
MatchPredicateStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
RepeatUnrollStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
PathRetractionStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
FilterRankingStrategy        [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
InlineFilterStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
AdjacentToIncidentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
CountStrategy                [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
LazyBarrierStrategy          [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
TinkerGraphCountStrategy     [P]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
TinkerGraphStepStrategy      [P]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
ProfileStrategy              [F]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
StandardVerificationStrategy [V]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]

Final Traversal                    [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), VertexStep(BOTH,vertex)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, following @stephen comment above, I just want to share a link to a blog that among a other goes in depth in explaining the famous [LazyBarrierStrategy](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-gremlin-implementation-of-the-gremlin-traversal-machine)